# Stripping empty attributes from Laravel model before saving

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to strip all empty fields from being submitted into my database from the form (using Mongo - Moloquent extends Eloquent).

I've got a base model:

```
class Base extends Moloquent {
  public static function boot(){
    parent::boot();
    static::saving( function($model){
      $arr = $model->toArray();
      $removed = array_diff($arr, array_filter($arr));
      foreach($removed as $k => $v) $model->__unset($k);
      return true;
    });
  }
}
```

And then extend it:

```
class MyModel extends Base{
  public static function boot(){
    parent::boot()
  }
}
```

But it has no effect on the child class (MyModel); I think I'm just missing something obvious that my [current] tunnel vision won't let me see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who comes looking for a solution; I setup a middleware to strip out all empty input fields, and then did the same in the saving method.

```
/* app/Http/Middleware/StripRequest.php */

use Closure;
class StripRequest {
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
    $request->replace(array_filter($request->all()));
    return $next($request);
  }
}
```

Remember to add it in the Kernel `$middleware`:

```
/* app/Http/Kernel.php */

protected $middleware = [
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
    'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
    'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
    'app\Http\Middleware\StripRequest',
];
```

From there I used the same models as specified above. Just remember to use `parent::__construct()` in your constructors or call parent in any other methods. The method that worked for me:

```
/* app/Models/Base.php */

static::saving(function($model){
  // Clear out the empty attributes
  $keep = array_filter($model->getAttributes(), function($item){ return empty($item); });
  foreach($keep as $k => $v) $model->unset($k);

  // Have to return true
  return true;
});
```

I used `unset()` from https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#mongodb-specific-operations

Answer (score 1):

Eloquent's base model has a method called setRawAttributes:

```
/**
 * Set the array of model attributes. No checking is done.
 *
 * @param  array  $attributes
 * @param  bool   $sync
 * @return void
 */
public function setRawAttributes(array $attributes, $sync = false)
{
    $this->attributes = $attributes;

    if ($sync) $this->syncOriginal();
}
```

If Moloquent extends this class or has a method like this you can use it after filtering the attributes array, like:

```
$model->setRawAttributes(array_filter($model->getAttributes()));
```

Comment: This didn't work - it's as if `MyModel` doesn't actually extend from `Base` / use the parent `boot` method.

Comment: @ShazAmjad It should have. The package you're using is `jenssegers/laravel-mongodb`, right? They do extend the base model: `abstract class Model extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {` then the `Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model` has `abstract class Model extends \Jenssegers\Eloquent\Model {`. What error did you get?

Comment: Yup that's the one - no errors, nothing. I tried `return false` in the `Base` model's `static::saving` and yet the model still saves any updated data; which is why I'm wondering how best to check if `MyModel` is actually using the parent `Base` model's `boot` method...

Comment: How about the good ol' `dd` everywhere? Open up the Moloquent model and dump some `dd()`'s in there and check what is being called and what isn't.

Comment: Incredibly strange - I can't get any of the model events in `boot()`, in the base nor the extended model.

Comment: Stupid of all mistakes; my `constructor` was missing `parent::__constructor`. My original method works now, but `->setRawAttributes()` doesn't quite work with mongo; I have to use [`->unset($key)`](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#mongodb-specific-operations)